# How close do Qt libraries have to match (COMPILE vs RUNTIME)

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, version

I have an app which uses Qt5 libraries.  I am compiling my app against Qt 5.6.1 but not all of my users have updated to the latest Qt5 libraries, in fact one user is still on Qt 5.4.0

I discovered that I am using a method introduced in Qt 5.5 - yet the app still runs with the user using Qt 5.4.0 (I assume he hasn't run the function with the method introduced in Qt 5.5.0)

So how close does the COMPILED against Qt library have to match the RUNTIME Qt library?  Must RUNTIME version >= COMPILETIME version?  Or must RUNTIME version >= version with methods I use?

Answer (score 0):

Read this brief [article](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Version-Compatibility) about compatibility.

Performing `ldd qtapp | grep -i qt` on linux gives me this output

```
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f3003cc3000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f300419a000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f30046e3000)
```

From this I understand that if you in future update your Qt version, say from Qt 5.4 to Qt 5.5, then there should not be any issue. Its generally safe.

However, what you are doing is **potentially dangerous** and asking for trouble. I would call it playing with a venomous snake and saying it has not yet bit me. Sooner or later it will.

Using methods introduced in 5.5 and then letting your users use 5.4 is not the right thing to do.

If your clients are using 5.4, I very strongly recommend that you too use version 5.4. If they upgrade to version 5.6, your code will still run, no crashes can occur. If you badly need version 5.6, I would suggest ship the 5.6 dlls with the application and tell the users it is an important upgrade.